# Pandas KeyError using pivot

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, keyerror

I'm new to Python and I would like to use Python to replicate a common excel task. If such a question has already been answered, please let me know.  I've been unable to find it.   I have the following pandas dataframe (data):

```
Date    Stage   SubStage    Value
12/31/2015   1.00   a   0.896882891
1/1/2016     1.00   a   0.0458843
1/2/2016     1.00   a   0.126805588
1/3/2016     1.00   b   0.615824461
1/4/2016     1.00   b   0.245092069
1/5/2016     1.00   c   0.121936318
1/6/2016     1.00   c   0.170198128
1/7/2016     1.00   c   0.735872415
1/8/2016     1.00   c   0.542361912
1/4/2016     2.00   a   0.723769247
1/5/2016     2.00   a   0.305570257
1/6/2016     2.00   b   0.47461605
1/7/2016     2.00   b   0.173702623
1/8/2016     2.00   c   0.969260251
1/9/2016     2.00   c   0.017170798
```

In excel, I can use a pivot table to produce the following:

[image: excel pivot table using 'data']

It seems reasonable to do the following in python:

```
data.pivot(index='Date',
           columns=['Stage', 'SubStage'],
           values='Value')
```

But that produces:

```
KeyError: 'Level Stage not found'
```

What gives?

Comment: do your column labels have trailing or leading whitespace? check by inspecting with `data.columns`

Comment: They do not: 

data.columns
Index(['Date', 'Stage', 'SubStage', 'Value'], dtype='object')

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want `.pivot_table`, not `.pivot`.

```
import pandas
from io import StringIO

x = StringIO("""\
Date    Stage   SubStage    Value
12/31/2015   1.00   a   0.896882891
1/1/2016     1.00   a   0.0458843
1/2/2016     1.00   a   0.126805588
1/3/2016     1.00   b   0.615824461
1/4/2016     1.00   b   0.245092069
1/5/2016     1.00   c   0.121936318
1/6/2016     1.00   c   0.170198128
1/7/2016     1.00   c   0.735872415
1/8/2016     1.00   c   0.542361912
1/4/2016     2.00   a   0.723769247
1/5/2016     2.00   a   0.305570257
1/6/2016     2.00   b   0.47461605
1/7/2016     2.00   b   0.173702623
1/8/2016     2.00   c   0.969260251
1/9/2016     2.00   c   0.017170798
""")

df = pandas.read_table(x, sep='\s+')
xtab = df.pivot_table(index='Date', columns=['Stage','SubStage'], values='Value')
print(xtab.to_string(na_rep='--'))
```

And that gives me:

```
Stage            1.0                           2.0                    
SubStage           a         b         c         a         b         c
Date                                                                  
1/1/2016    0.045884        --        --        --        --        --
1/2/2016    0.126806        --        --        --        --        --
1/3/2016          --  0.615824        --        --        --        --
1/4/2016          --  0.245092        --  0.723769        --        --
1/5/2016          --        --  0.121936  0.305570        --        --
1/6/2016          --        --  0.170198        --  0.474616        --
1/7/2016          --        --  0.735872        --  0.173703        --
1/8/2016          --        --  0.542362        --        --  0.969260
1/9/2016          --        --        --        --        --  0.017171
12/31/2015  0.896883        --        --        --        --        --
```

Comment: This is helpful.  Generally speaking, is pivot_table as opposed to pivot the agreed upon best practice? Why in the world are there two functions for the same concept?

Comment: They serve different purposes, but I couldn't tell you what they are. I always `stack/unstack` with a multi-level index to do something like this. @trob

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you!

Comment: For the above dataframe, we get the same results with pivot() as well. Why was OP unable to use pivot?