# Transpose variables in row to column by subject(case) and date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-cleaning

I'm looking to see if it is even possible to do using python.
I have more than 100 subjects, several variables extracted on different days; I want to make the variable names (written in rows) into column names and move its values accordingly. 
In case it doesn't make sense, I'm attaching a screenshot of what I want to do using Python. 
Please let me know if it is even possible, and if so, how? 
I'm not necessarily looking for specific script, but just the general flow? 
Thanks!

[LEFT: what I have. RIGHT: what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZtU1.png)

Comment: Hi hek999, welcome to SO!  Here are some tips to get the best out of this site  Firstly, it's best to search for solutions before you post a question.  E.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37150248/pandas-keyerror-using-pivot) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe).  Also, [please don't post pictures of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/9576876) (or data).  It's better to include a little of both as text.  Lastly, something like this will do the trick `df.pivot_table(index='subjID', columns='var_names', values='var_values')`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
df.groupby('subjID').apply(lambda grp: grp.pivot(
    index='date', columns='var_names', values='var_values'))\
    .rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()
```

Initially I thought about just *pivot* with index set to *subjID* and
*date*, but unfortunately *pivot* does not serve such a case.

I found that this is a bug and has beed reported on *Pandas* GitHub as issue *21425*.

So to circumvent this limitation, I grouped by *subjID* and then
called *pivot* with *index='date'* on each group.

To see the need for *rename_axis* and *reset_index*, run my code
without these fuctions and the difference should be obvious.

Comment: Thank Valdi_Bo! I'll def try this out.

Comment: Why not `pivot_table` ?

Comment: *pivot_table* can be used, e.g. with *aggfunc=np.sum*, but it is designed rather for cases where there are **multiple** rows for a single index value (so some aggregation is needed). But in this case there is a **sigle** value for each index, so *pivot* seems a more natural choice.